# Update part of text in document

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, text, replace

I have a `.xal` document which can be opened with notepad just fine. Below is the part of it that is important to me:

> ...
>   magV=1
>   invert=0
>   text=010000002378431411**140526**93183714
>
> [Pri1]
>   enabled=0
>   ...

I would like to create a script, which would auto replace part of text `140526` in line 128 (it is some old date - 26.05.2014) and replace it with the current date.
For example: today it should be `160816`, tommorrow there should be `160817`, etc.

**As said before text is in line 128, characters are from 24 to 30.**

If searched around (SED for WIN, VBA, Powershell,...) but i didn't find anything that could work.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Still exprementing but $1 = get-content .\examplefile
$1[128] will select row 128, then it shouldn't be to hard to use regex or something like that to replace the charatchers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using PowerShell:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file_path'
$content[127] = $content[127] -replace '(.{24}).{6}', ('${{1}}{0}' -f (Get-Date).ToString('yyMMdd'))
$content | Set-Content 'your_file_path'
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried your solution but it's not (yet) ok. I debug the code in Powershell ISE and in the midle of debuging i get this  -> 01000000237843141111608164052693183714. As you can see there is still previous text (140526) in it and after that today's date is added. The output should be 01000000237843141116081693183714. Ok but in the end when i check output file, there is still the same text on line 128 as it is in input file -> 01000000237843141114052693183714, looks like nothing has been changed at all??

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it again.

Comment: Now all i get in my output file is ->  text=01000000237843141111608164052693183714. There need to be other text too.

Comment: Arg, sorry - Im not able to test the script since I don't have an example file.  Should be fixed now...

Comment: I'm thankful for your help so not complaining at all :) Now it's working great except for one thing mentioned above -> old text (140526 ) should be replaced with new one (160816), now they are side by side if you look my output 010000002378431411*1[160816]40526*93183714. I marked old text between ** and new text between [ ].

Comment: I edited my answer again to fix that ;-). Please consider to accepting the answer if your question is solved.

Comment: Perfect! I really thank you for all your help, i've learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

works fine if you do a windows batch file and using sed

Basically, use `set` and built-in `DATE` environment variable to extract year, month, day as a 6-digit string (`DATE` contains `yy/mm/dd`, slashes need to be removed)
Then apply sed on line 128 only, creating one group, replacing the group + the 6 next chars by the same group + the new date.

The `-i` flag allows to perform in-place replacement so input file is updated instead of outputing the result in standard output.

```
set D=%DATE%
set D=%D:~0,2%%D:~3,2%%D:~6,2%
echo %D%
sed -i "128s/\(text=..................\)....../\1%D%/" input.txt
```